# Pandas sum of count per percentile of rows

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

Here is a [link to a working example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rJYaLOSHdbyH-msmjdg12Q3QN63D3ki5?usp=sharing) on Google Colaboratory.

I have a dataset that represents the reviews (between 0.0 to 10.0) that users have left on various books. It looks like this:

```
         user      sum  count      mean
0           2      0.0      1  0.000000
60223  159665      8.0      1  8.000000
60222  159662      8.0      1  8.000000
60221  159655      8.0      1  8.000000
60220  159651      5.0      1  5.000000
...       ...      ...    ...       ...
13576   35859   6294.0   5850  1.075897
37356   98391  51418.0   5891  8.728230
58113  153662  17025.0   6109  2.786872
74815  198711    123.0   7550  0.016291
4213    11676  62092.0  13602  4.564917
```

The first rows have 1 review while the last ones have thousands. I want to see the distribution of the reviews across the user population. I researched percentile or binning data with Pandas and found [pd.qcut](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html) and [pd.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) but using those, I was unable to get the format in the way I want it.

This is what I'm looking to get.

```
# users: reviews
# top 10%: 65K rev
# 10%-20%: 23K rev
# etc...
```

I could not figure out a "Pandas" way to do it so I wrote a loop to generate the data in that format myself and graph it.

```
SLICE_NUMBERS = 5
step_size = int(user_count/SLICE_NUMBERS)
labels = ['100-80', '80-60', '60-40', '40-20', '0-20']
count_per_percentile = []
for chunk_i in range(SLICE_NUMBERS):
  start_index = step_size * chunk_i;
  end_index = start_index + step_size;
  slice_sum = most_active_list.iloc[start_index:end_index]['count'].sum()
  count_per_percentile.append(slice_sum)

print(labels)
print(count_per_percentile) // [21056, 21056, 25058, 62447, 992902]
```

How can I achieve the same outcome more directly with the library?

Comment: Can you provide some sample input data

Comment: @sayandasgupta I added a link to a Google Colab link

Comment: The reason you couldn't apply `pd.cut/pd.qcut` to your data was the fact that in based on your real data value 1 as a number of reviews ends as 55 percentile, 80 percentile gives 5 reviews, 90 only 12 and 95 is responsible for 55 reviews. Considering most active user with 13602 reviews `pd.qcut` couldn't assign 5 even bins due to the fact more than 2 bins have this same edge values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `qcut` to create the slices, in a `groupby.sum`. So with the sample data given slightly modified to avoid duplicated edges on this small sample (I replaced all the ones in count by 1,2,3,4,5)

```
count_per_percentile = (
    df['count']
      .groupby(pd.qcut(df['count'], q=[0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1])).sum()
      .tolist()
)
print(count_per_percentile)
# [3, 7, 5855, 12000, 21152]
```

being the same result as with your method.

In case your real data has too many 1, you could also use `np.array_split` so

```
count_per_percentile  = [_s.sum() for _s in np.array_split(df['count'].sort_values(),5)]
print(count_per_percentile)
# [3, 7, 5855, 12000, 21152] #same result
```

Comment: What is the difference in using `.rank(method='first')` and `np.array_split` ?

Comment: I also tried to adapt it to do the same calculation but on the `mean` instead of the `count` and it gave me something unexpected as well... I edited my question